# Mastercard Hosted Checkout Tokenised Cards

Tags: payment, mastercard, 3d-secure

This is something we've asked Mastercard about, however, I haven't been able to get a clear answer from them.  Perhaps someone has implemented this and can assist.  In our initial emails with them, it was implied that the Hosted Checkout can work with tokenized cards.

We are implementing the Hosted Checkout solution from Mastercard into our mobile app.  [We've been using these integration guidelines.](https://secure.eu.tnspayments.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US#x_BP)

We are doing a two-step journey, where we are performing a *VERIFY* using the Hosted Checkout, and submitting the *PAY* operation afterward in a separate call.

The user has the option after going through the Hosted Checkout to save (tokenize) their card through MPGS.

**The bit I'm stuck on:**  Is it possible to supply a card token to the Hosted Checkout, so that the user can verify an existing card if needed through a 3DS2 flow, without having to enter the card details again?

I've tried sending the card token through to the *CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION* request, but this seemingly has no impact - the user still needs to enter their card details, and then, because they have card details entered, those override any token for the payment.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have same kind of requirement for another payment gateway which has almost same process as Mastercard. Did you find any work around for this ?

Comment: Hi, i am having the same journey verify then pay. when i open hosted checkout i charge the user 1$ as a verification then tokenize card. How do i refund bank 1$ charged?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API process for this tokenization part.

URL: [https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/62/merchant/{merchantId}/order/{orderid}/transaction/{transactionid}](https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/62/merchant/%7BmerchantId%7D/order/%7Borderid%7D/transaction/%7Btransactionid%7D)

HTTP Method :PUT

Request

```
{
   "apiOperation":"PAY",
   "order":{
      "amount":"1.25",
      "currency":"LKR"
   },
   "session":{
      "id":"SESSION0002257639145N66745126J0"
   },
   "sourceOfFunds":{
      "token":"9407378747428845",
      "type":"CARD"
   }
}
```